# Ruling striking down the Affordable Care Act

Tags: precedent

What does Friday's ruling mean? I thought the Supreme Court already upheld the individual mandate and most aspects of the law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [the ruling](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.txnd.299449/gov.uscourts.txnd.299449.211.0.pdf), the earlier Supreme Court ruling in [NFIB v. Sebelius](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/567/519/), 567 U.S. 519, was handed down prior to passage of the Tax Cuts and Jobs Act of 2017. One provision of that act was to reduce the ACA shared responsibility payment to zero. It was crucial to the earlier ruling that Congress has the power to tax: it is not within the scope of the Interstate Commerce powers (this was part of the holding in that case). Since there is now no tax, there is no tax-based authority to impose this obligation. What it "means" is that this ruling will be appealed and presumably the argument will continue to the 5th Circuit, ultimately to the Supreme Court. At this point, one can only speculate about the final outcome.

Comment: From the layman's POV, this seems strange.  The ACA was "constitutional" (layman's understanding: "consistant with the Constitution" with a tax penalty. Now with a tax penalty of 0 dollars, it becomes "unconstitutional" (layman's understanding: "inconsistant with the Constitution"). Recall that the tax penalty was not erased with the 2017 tax act, just the value of the penalty was reduced to zero. Would the ACA become constitutional again if the penalty were raised from zero to 1 cent?  Strange.

Comment: And the appeal may well use that "no tax" vs. "zero tax" distinction to good effect.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that a rule with no penalty for violating it can be essential to a complex, statutory scheme. So even if the individual mandate is no longer justifiable as an exercise of the taxing power, that the act still works without any penalty for violating it proves that it's a severable requirement. (As the 11th circuit found and the majority in NFIB v. Sibelius did not disturb.)